# Element change focus transition effect

Tags: css, focus, css-transitions

How can I implement an effect on focus change from element to another element.

Like for example check this site in chrome.

http://webaim.org/

It has some transition effect for jumping focus from one element to another.

I want the same effect. I have tried the following css but it is not working.

```
color: #BF1722;
transition: color 0.2s ease-in, text-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in, text-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
text-shadow: #bbb 1px 1px 1px;
```

Is there any javascript involved? OR I'm missing something in the css?

Comment: can u show us more code? please create a fiddle

Comment: It can be done only using JavaScript. See this for more information: https://github.com/NV/flying-focus

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```css
a {
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in, text-shadow 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.25s linear 0s;
}

a:hover {
    text-shadow: #bbb 1px 1px 1px;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    color: #BF1722;
}
```

```html
<a>test test test test</a>
```

---

You need to have 2 declarations. First the basic rule, and the second "hover" rule.

The first rule describes the standard with the transition to the second rule.
The second rule just have the changed options.

Comment: Nopes. He means the flying focus transition.

Comment: If it's not you, I am really sorry. I have already flagged the issue to mods, let them have a look. I am sorry if I have unintentionally offended you! `:(`

Answer (score 0):

That's a JavaScript UI concept, using `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements. The full source code is available here: [GitHub - NV/flying-focus](https://github.com/NV/flying-focus).

There's also an explanation of how it works in [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyIE9vjy8Zo).

**Snippet**

```html
<script src="http://n12v.com/focus-transition/flying-focus.js"></script>
<input /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input />
```

To clarify the answer I wrote is right, I can get a screenshot from [Who uses Flying Focus: In the Wild](https://github.com/NV/flying-focus/wiki/In-the-Wild), which contains WebAIM.org, as asked by the OP.

[image: preview]